# Retrieve parameter value passed into function as a string

Tags: r, string, list, function

I have a large list of variables / dataframes which are named in an easy to identify manner.

For example `_big_list = list(runner5_data, runner11_data, runner83_data)` and so on.

I want to perform a loop where I dump each of these data frames into a function where it does stuff but then also is able to take the name of my parameter value and add it as a new column for example....

At the end I want to return it back into a new list...

```
place_holder_list = list()
my_funct = function(data_from_list) {
                    df$helpme = dQuote(data_from_list) # or something similar?     
                    # so df$helpme = 'iris' or 'mtcars', etc
                    # do other stuff
                    return(df)
}

ex_list = list(iris, mtcars)
for (each_df in ex_list){
    my_funct(each_df)   #help appending to list...new column in df should be iris$helpme = 'iris'
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `df`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with `Map`

```
ex_list1 <- Map(cbind, ex_list, helpme = c("iris", "mtcars"))
lapply(ex_list1, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species helpme
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   iris
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   iris

#[[2]]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb helpme
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 mtcars
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 mtcars
```

If we need, we can create a function to do this

```
f1 <- function(...) {
       dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
       helpme <- unlist(sapply(dots, deparse))
       lst <- list(...)
       Map(cbind, lst, helpme = helpme)
}

f1(mtcars)
f1(iris, mtcars)
```